# Disable "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chromium" programatically

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, chromium

I see this "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chromium" on Chrome's and Chromium's settings.

[image]

I would like to change disable it when starting browser with Selenium. I didn't find any chrome option, nor any chrome argument that would help.

I have check [this code of Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc), where are all the prefs but I didn't find anything regarding to cookies, site data, quit, exit, cleanup.

Also not finding any relevant on the chromium arguments:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

Answer (score 2):

Try using chrome capabilities:

```
from selenium import webdriver

caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['deleteDataPostSession'] = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

This toggles the setting to off me when i kick it off with python:

[image]

---

[update]

In the comments i was asked how i found this - answer is i looked at the source and followed the white rabbit..

I started with the text for the settings. I searched for `Clear cookies and site data`

In this file: `settings_google_chrome_strings.grdp` i got this hit:

```
  <!-- Cookie Settings Page -->
  <message name="IDS_SETTINGS_SITE_SETTINGS_DELETE_DATA_POST_SESSION" desc="Label for the checkbox that allows the user to automatically delete their cookies and site data at the end of the browser session.">
    Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome
  </message>
```

I could see that wasn't quite right. So i searched for the name of the setting, and that got one hit in file: `md_settings_localized_strings_provider.cc`

```
      {"deleteDataPostSession",
       IDS_SETTINGS_SITE_SETTINGS_DELETE_DATA_POST_SESSION},
```

That looked about right for what i usually stick into capabilities... All that was left was to test it - and it worked.

Comment: Shouldn't doubt me mate :-) Just look up the name of setting in the chromium source and set it as needed. Doesn't work on all instances but this one did

Comment: Where did you find "deleteDataPostSession"? I couldn't find it in the source
By the way it works

Comment: @Tomi - one sec - i'll add a few lines in the post about it :-)

Comment: Thanks, please also check my answer. I use .NET and not sure if this is the proper way of doing it. `AddAdditionalChromeOption(string, object)` was not working

Answer (score 0):

RichEdwards helped me to solve it. In .NET I used the following code:

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("deleteDataPostSession", false);
```

The flag will still be enabled, but the cookies are present in the cookies store on the profile path. On the profile path's Default folder's Preferences file, I could see the change:

```
"deleteDataPostSession":false
```

What is not clear yet from me, where can you search for the proper preference name like `deleteDataPostSession`? I couldn't find anything like this in the chromium code.

Comment: Just added it how i found  it my answer - hope that helps mate :-)

Comment: If c# - you might want to use `DesiredCapabilities` instead of chrome options. Do you need me to put something together or have you got this from here?  (happy to help - but just take me time to spin up VS to make sure i share the right answer)

Comment: DesiredCapabilities didn't make it and it is also deprecated in C# and Java. Please set it if you have some time