# Selenium doesn't keep cache valid

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a python software with selenium. The problem is I want my script and selenium to save cookies after logging in. I save cookies using both "pickle" module and the below argument:

```
opts.add_argument("user-data-dir=cachedD")
```

But when I quit the browser and then launch it again and going to the same URL as it left off, the website again redirects to the login page. The website is using "[moodle](https://moodle.org/)", and I guess it's cookies expire after quitting the browser. How can I save cookies and continue where it left off? I should say that there's just a maximum 15 seconds gap between two launches.

Answer (score 0):

You're potentially not using the tag correctly.

With this tag you specify a folder path. If you review [this](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#user-data-dir) page:

> --user-data-dir
> **Directory** where the browser stores the user profile. ↪

That link may not look right, but the [chromium page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) say that's the right list.

Historically, I've had success with:

```
.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Temp")
```

If that is still not working as you expect, there are a few other things you can look at.

- Review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300851/disable-clear-cookies-and-site-data-when-you-quit-chromium-programatically/63301426#63301426) page - cookies can be deleted when you close your browser. You'll want to verify the value of this option.
- Another check is to open your chromedriver via selenium and goto [chrome://version/](http://chrome://version/)  . From here you can review what you're running and you'll see there are *a lot* more tags that are enabled by default. You should check that these match up to how you want your browser to behave.